# WDCloud - What is best protocol to connect via Mac OSX, SMB or AFP

Tags: networking, mac, smb, afp

I have a MacbookAir, and [WD_EX2](https://www.wdc.com/products/network-attached-storage/my-cloud-expert-series-ex2-ultra.html).
Everything runs OK for more than I year.

Since there is at leat two ways to make a connection I would like to know what is right/best protocol to connect : SMB or AFP. Today I'm using AFP.

By the way, and perhaps it has nothing to do with protocal selection : after macbook goes into STBY mode, sometimes it takes a while ( a long while ) to restore connection, and it is a real annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

Recent macOS versions have officially deprecated AFP in favor of SMBv2 (with AAPL extensions). So *in general,* SMBv2 would be the preferred choice.

However, WD's "My Cloud" firmware seems to be using a very old version of the Samba service ([a pre-release of 4.0](https://community.wd.com/t/configuring-samba-for-smb3/190957/15) according to the forums), so I wouldn't really expect it to handle SMBv2 correctly – or even understand it at all.

The forum post is from January 2017; I'm not sure if anything has changed over the year, but if not, then AFP might be a better option at the moment.

Comment: thank you for your answer. WD seems infavour of SMB - https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=2686

Comment: but - somehow it seems that AFP connect seemlessly to mac OS ( less the issue i mentioned in my question).